# Need help putting button on top of carousel img

Tags: html, css, sass

My image in the carousel is currently covering my button. Any help on getting the button to sit on top of the image would be greatly appreciated.

carousel.component.html

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="assets/myimg8.jpg" class="d-block w-100 myImg" alt="...">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark myButton">Dark</button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="assets/myimg.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="assets/myimg6.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

carouel.component.scss

```
.carousel-item{
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-item button {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Use `z-index` on the button greater than `image` or any `z-index` value in document

Comment: I tried adding the z-index where the button is higher than the image and that wasn't working either

Comment: If you are mentioning `position: absolute` you must use either of these properties  `top, bottom, left, right`. Try giving `bottom: 0`

Comment: This worked Shashank Gb. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your problem is not with the `z-index` property.
Replace

```css
position: absolute;
```

with

```css
position: relative;
```

and you'll see it again.

Now, once the relative value has been used, you can use one of the following properties : `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `right`.

If you want your button to sit on top of the image, a solution could be this :

```css
.carousel-inner button {
  position: relative;
  top: -7em;
}
```

Comment: If I do this it just places the button underneath the image rather than on top of it

Comment: I tested your code and it's working with me. Try using z-index for the button though... Like for example z-index: 1000; or a higher value.

Comment: This does work and puts the button on top of the image, but it creates a whole row of white space from the button. Do you have any suggestions on how to get rid of that. I am new to development so I appreciate the help.

Comment: Sure I will help you. Please send me a screenshot showing what you're talking about, and tell me what do you want now exactly.